# how to send data from java service class to kotlin activity class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

**This is my Java service class FCM**

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "FCM Data Tag" ;

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
   
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        String data=  remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
       String details[] = (data.split("\n"));
       String username,location,serviceType,date,time,area;
        username=details[0];
        location=details[1];
        serviceType=details[2];
        date=details[3];
        time=details[4];
        area=details[5];

        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FragmentHome.class);
        i.putExtra("user",username);
        i.putExtra("loc",location);
        i.putExtra("type",serviceType);
        i.putExtra("Date",date);
        i.putExtra("Time",time);
        i.putExtra("Area",area);


    }
```

---

And i dont know how to receieve the data in kotlin class.

Comment: Look up local broadcast receiver

Comment: in that case if you want a the data with on notificaiton click use local broad cast when your app is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onCreate method of kotlin activity you need to get these variable as below -

```
val user:String = intent.getStringExtra("user")
val loc:String = intent.getStringExtra("loc")
val type:String = intent.getStringExtra("type")
val date:String = intent.getStringExtra("Date")
val time:String = intent.getStringExtra("Time")
val area:String = intent.getStringExtra("Area")
```

Comment: I tried this , val broadCastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
  override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
   val user: String? = intent?.getStringExtra("user")
   tvUser.text = user
   Toast.makeText(requireContext(),user,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }
 }  but textview is not updating

Comment: pls tell the mehod to receive, should i use intent filter ?

Comment: Do share the class where you want to receive intent dara

Comment: I used intent filter Now it works thank you

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer